# Install php 5.6.5 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, magento

I need help in installing php 5.6.5 in my ubuntu 16.04 for my Magento 2.1 website.

I tried installing php through these commands:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip
```

But when i do `php -v` it gives me this version:

```
PHP 5.6.30-12~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Is there a way to upgrade 5.6.30 to 5.6.5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

5.6.30 is a much newer version then 5.6.5. Version numbers are not decimal numbers but counters, so `4.11` would be newer then `4.2`. There are 25 releases between PHP 5.6.5 and 5.6.30.

Also, according to http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html, Magento just needs PHP 5.4.x or newer, so the stock Ubuntu version is just fine.

Comment: "I need help in installing php 5.6.5 in my ubuntu 16.04 for my Magento 2.1 website."

Magento 1.X has different requirements than Magento 2.1

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: OK, but 5.6.30 is still fine and *much* better suited then 5.6.5.

Comment: Yeah, but Magento 2.1 won't work with that version though.

Comment: Then you have another problem that won't be fixed by installing a hopelessly outdated, insecure and unsupported version of PHP. Maybe ask a question about your actual problem... Also, according to your link, it should work because `5.6.5–5.6.x` means that every version from 5.6.5 and later, including 5.6.30,  is supported by Magento.